# CSS trick to display multiple divs

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to separate my window in 2 equal parts, same height but width is 50% for each.

So I used this

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    height : 100%;       
}

.column {
    flex: 1;
    height : 100%;
}

.column-one {
    order: 1;

}
.column-two {
    order: 2;        
}
```

My html is structured like this

```
<div class="container">

<div class="column column-one"> Column 1
    <div  class="x" id="sliceX" ></div>
    <div  class="y" id="sliceY"></div>
    <div  class="z" id="sliceZ"></div>
</div>

<div class="column column-two"> Column 2
    <div  class="x" id="sliceX2"> </div>
    <div  class="y" id="sliceY2"></div>
    <div  class="z" id="sliceZ2"></div>
</div>

</div>
```

This is working well.

Now I want that my `.x` will take 100% of width but 50% of height. `.y` and `.z` will be displayed just after. Both taking 50% of height(the rest). But each class will only take 50% of width so `.y` will be displayed on the left and `.z` on the right

Like this:

```
Col1 Col2
xxxx xxxx
xxxx xxxx
yyzz yyzz
yyzz yyzz
```

How can I structure my css get this working with my actual separation in 2 columns ?

Comment: You mean height when you say length?

Comment: @pit Yes, sorry. I edited my post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you could try is to make your `.column` a flex container also and set it's wrap to allowing wrapping. Then set `.x` to `width:100%;` and `.y, .z` to `width:50%;` then give them all a `height:50%;`

Like this:

```
.column {
    flex: 1;
    height : 100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.x{
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
}
.y, .z{
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mypa0z71/).

Comment: Nice answer.  Adding borders to visualize it helps a little though: https://jsfiddle.net/mypa0z71/

Comment: @JosephMarikle yes it does indeed! I will update my answer to use your fiddle

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably have best results with a second `flex` definition. You can use `flex-wrap` to wrap the layout quite effectively. Something like this:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.column {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.x {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
}
.y, .z {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.x {background-color: #ff8080}
.y {background-color: #80ff80}
.z {background-color: #8080ff}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column column-one">
    <div class="x" id="sliceX"></div>
    <div class="y" id="sliceY"></div>
    <div class="z" id="sliceZ"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="column column-two">
    <div class="x" id="sliceX2"></div>
    <div class="y" id="sliceY2"></div>
    <div class="z" id="sliceZ2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above, the `.x` takes 100% of the width, pushing the `.y` and `.z` onto the second row. Each of these then takes 50% of the width, making a nice result. You can of course further adjust the balance to 30/70 or anything you choose.

Great job on using Flex, by the way - it's definitely a great tool for this job :)